# Phpfox plugins 3.7.7

Tags: php, plugins, smarty, call, phpfox

Whats is the difference between

```
(($sPlugin = Phpfox_Plugin::get('blog.service_process__start')) ? eval($sPlugin) : false);
```

and

```
{plugin call='blog.template_controller_add_hidden_form'}
```

Comment: i think one for php and the second for html))

Comment: yes you are write @sAs59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(($sPlugin = Phpfox_Plugin::get('blog.service_process__start')) ? eval($sPlugin) : false); 

this syntax  used in class files (controller,block,service) 

and


{plugin call='blog.template_controller_add_hidden_form'}

this syntax used in template file (controller,block)
```